# html javascript implementing id into javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
 <p id="ok"></p>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("ok").innerHTML =
 Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        </script>
 <script>
        if (ok >=6){
        winner="yes"
        else 
        loser="no"
    }
</script>
```

how do I add ok as a variable for my random number

Comment: Where are you defining the variable `ok`?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, just a few issues with your code. First you need to be setting the random number to a variable, you can then pass that variable into the element using `innerHTML`. Then you plug the variable into your conditional statement. Something like this:

```js
var val = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
console.log(val);

document.getElementById("ok").innerHTML = val;
 

if (val >=6){
  console.log('win');
} else {
  console.log('lose');
}
```

```html
<p id="ok"></p>
```

Comment: deleted one set of script tags and combined the whole code